# flex combobox arrow custom image

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, skinning, flex3

In my Flex AIR application I have to customize the Combobox with custom arrow icon. I got the properties to change its color but didn't get any property to change the icon itself. After Googling I got some links of skinning the combobox but they were for FLASH CS4, but I am on Flex.

Not getting any solution. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Style>
    ComboBox {
        up-skin :  Embed(source="Pulldown_def.png");
        down-skin : Embed(source="Pulldown_def.png");
        over-skin : Embed(source="Pulldown_def.png");       
    }
</mx:Style>
<mx:Array id="dp">
    <mx:Object label="test1" />
    <mx:Object label="test2" />
</mx:Array>
<mx:ComboBox id="cbx" x="51" y="43" dataProvider="{dp}" labelField="label" ></mx:ComboBox>
```

It is not working for me :(
It applies the image over whole Combobox. I need to replace the arrow image. 
Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom skin and set the `skin`, `upSkin`, `downSkin` and `overSkin` [style attributes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ComboBase.html#styleSummary) of the ComboBox to that class. The default value is `ComboBoxArrowSkin`

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `ComboBoxArrowSkin` draws the ENTIRE ComboBox. There is no style attribute for the icon itself - you'll have to write your own skin. Read through ComboBox.as and ComboBoxArrowSkin.as and you'll see what's going on there. It's ugly. I would consider deriving my own class from `ComboBoxArrowSkin` and tweaking the arrow drawing yourself. It happens at the end of `updateDisplayList()`:

```
// Draw the triangle.
g.beginFill(arrowColor);
g.moveTo(w - 11.5, h / 2 + 3);
g.lineTo(w - 15, h / 2 - 2);
g.lineTo(w - 8, h / 2 - 2);
g.lineTo(w - 11.5, h / 2 + 3);
g.endFill();
```